# Jewish word definitions?

Tags: hebrew

I am new to this site and wish to be involved in questions and answers ( As one who has studied the trinity doctrine for many years I may be of some help). As I read through  various posts I see terms I am not familiar with as one who does not speak Hebrew. Is there a place where there is  glossary of common Judaic theological terms, especially those used in conversations about what is allowed Ben Noach and what is idolatry, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: there are many online resources with various words listed. Start with http://www.jewfaq.org/tocwords.htm

Comment: You might want to start with our very own [glossary](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/581/1713) here on Mi Yodeya

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Lawrence. Consider taking [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) short tour of the site. For general help see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help). Perhaps you would be interested in [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity?sort=newest&pageSize=30) 113 questions about Christianity. Hope to see you around.

Comment: Thank you both. I am a person who is leaving Christianity after many years. I had looked into converting to Judaism a few years ago, but the process seemed near impossible. The Noachide option is no different from what I currently do, except that I ( probably wrongly) observe Shabbat and Yom Kippur. These things mean very much to me and I cannot imagine life without Shabbat. It is the center of my world. I know this is going to be a long process so I am trying to get up to speed on the language. Thanks again.